# Determine the maximum value of N such that sum of all array elements doesn't exceed S

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials

You are given a positive integers S. Find 3D array A of dimensions N x N x N where any element A[i][j][k] of A equals i*k*(i+j+k) (1<=i,j,k<=N) such that sum of all array elements doesn't exceed.Determine a maximum value of N.

Constraints:
3 <= S <= 10^16

Eg: S=720

Approach:

Check for N=1. The only element in array A, A[1][1][1] = 3, which does not exceed S
Check for N=2, A[1][1][1]=3, A[1][1][2]=8, A[1][2][1]=4, A[1][2][2]=10, A[2][1][1]=8, A[2][1][2]=20, A[2][2][1]=10, A[2][2][2]=24, the sum equals to 87, which does not exceed S
Check for N=3. Sum equals to 720 which doesn't exceed S nor bigger value of N is possible
Hence max value of N is 3

Can we derive any equation for this problem

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question a bit. You are not given an array rather given $S$ you want to find the maximum value of $N$ for which the sum of all elements of the array of size $N \times N \times N$ constructed as described does not exceed $S$.

Answer (score 1):

In dimension $N$, the sum of all values of all $A[i][j][k]$ is equal to the sum $S(N):=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^Nik(i+j+k)$.
Splitting up the sum and using the identities $\sum_{i=1}^Ni=\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$, $\sum_{i=1}^Ni^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$, you can find the value of $S(N)$.
This will allow you to find to biggest $N$ such that $S(N)\leq S$ for a given $S$.